# Didn't get json array in App js file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, routes, angular-services

My service code look like belowed :-

```
data.service('SmartLearnerService', function ($http) {

//Get Single Records
this.get = function (id) {
    return $http.get("/api/Category/");
    }
});
```

Here is my controller code for App.js:-

```
$scope.questionlist = SmartLearnerService.get();

    $scope.questionlist.then(function (pl) {
        var res = pl.data;
        $scope.que = res.QuestionLabel;

    },
                 function (errorPl) {
                     console.log('failure loading Employee', errorPl);
                 });
    console.log($scope.questionlist);
```

Here is Controller code for web api controller :-

```
public class CategoryController : ApiController
{
    CommonDb db = new CommonDb();
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var Result = db.GetQuestionById().ToList();

        string message = "No Data Found";

        if (Result.Count() != 0)
        {
            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult()
            {
                Data = Result,
                JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }

        else
        {
            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult()
            {
                Data = message,
                JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
    }
   }
}
```

And here is div tag where i want to bind questions from json result using ng-repeat directive.

```
<div class="question" align="center">{{Questions.QuestionLabel}}</div>
```

i am facing problem while binding json array in controller's $scope.questionlist and i am successfully getting json result from web api controller.

Comment: `questionlist` is a promise, not really suitable for binding. You seem to be putting some data in `que` though at a guess, I'd say `pl.data.QuestionLabel` isn't defined as I would expect `pl.data` to be an array

Comment: ok i'd done like that but it's not works for me, now what should be the solution ???

Comment: Provide an example of the response data as well as how you would like to present it

Comment: ok i want to return json data in $scope.questionlist by this way :- $scope.questionlist = [
            { "QuestionID": "1", "QuestionLabel": "Why are mirrors often slightly curved (convex) ?", "Image": "zibra-crossing.jpg", "Correct": "two", "Explaination": "Question one explaination is goes here" },
....

    ];

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I had to guess (and that's exactly what I'm doing), you want something like this in your controller...

```
SmartLearnerService.get().success(function(questions) {
    $scope.questionList = questions;
});
```

or, if you're not a fan of the add-on `success` / `error` callbacks

```
SmartLearnerService.get().then(function(response) {
    $scope.questionList = response.data;
});
```

and in your template

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questionList">
    <div class="question" align="center">{{question.QuestionLabel}}</div>
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

This is totally assuming your C# controller returns JSON that looks something like...

```
 [{
     "QuestionID": "1",
     "QuestionLabel": "Why are mirrors often slightly curved (convex) ?",
     "Image": "zibra-crossing.jpg",
     "Correct": "two",
     "Explaination": "Question one explaination is goes here"
 }, {
 ...
 }]
```

Comment: the server responded with a status of 500

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
SmartLearnerService
            .get()
            .success(function (data, status) {
                if (status === 200) {
                    //your code to process data is here
                }else{alert(status)}
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                //TODO: Use nice alert.
                alert('Server request failed with status ' + status + ' while getting area in the ' + $item.Name);
            });
```

You will get the status code that you are receiving and then you can change the code accordingly.

The approach that I took in my case was to serialize using JsonConvert from NewtonSoft and then return the string of Json object instead of Json object itself to improve the speed.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say OP's (C#) controller only returns status 200

Comment: @Phil, It's possible that status code returned is not 200. I had to do some twisting in my code to get  200 status.